# Put android device to sleep programmatically and wake it up at a specific time

Tags: android

I am building an app that needs to run at a specific time and put the device to sleep mode after a specific time
Example : the app starts running at 8 A.M and at 10PM the device goes to sleep and wakes up again at 8 AM
I've searched and found that the goToSleep method in PowerManager is no longer used apparently.
Can broadcast receiver help in this case ? and if so how is this possible ? ( when the device is in sleep mode )

Comment: Please define what you mean by "sleep mode". Should the device power down or just go to "do not disturb" mode?

Comment: No what I mean is the device needs to go to standby mode / screen saver , The app is playing videos all day and at night ( 10PM ) I need to put the device in screensaver or standby mode ( black screen if possible ) and re awake the app in the morning

Comment: For obvious reasons It's not possible to put a device to sleep without the user doing it themself after doing some research, I've used AlarmManager to start a blanc activity and block the user from going back or exiting the app and after a specific time I wake it up.